# Kaltura KalturaMetadataListResponse print_r result

Tags: php, object, kaltura

I get the following returned result from a `print_r` of a variable returned from a `$metadataPlugin->metadata->listAction($filter, $pager)` function. I am trying to echo out the `[xml]` piece but can't figure out how to do it.

```
KalturaMetadataListResponse Object ( [objects] => Array ( [0] => KalturaMetadata Object ( [id] => 1 [partnerId] => 8 [metadataProfileId] => 2 [metadataProfileVersion] => 1 [metadataObjectType] => 1 [objectId] => 0 [version] => 1 [createdAt] => 1353093894 [updatedAt] => 1353093894 [status] => 1 [xml] => 1353049200 ) ) [totalCount] => 1 )
```

I have tried

```
echo $result['objects'][0]->xml;
```

and

```
echo $result[0]->xml;
```

with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should be

```
$result->objects[0]->xml
```

Just remember when looking at `print_r` or `var_dump` results that any time you see `Object (...)` that you will need to use `->` to access the property listed for that object.

So in this case, you have a base Object set as `$result`, which you then need to get the `objects` property from.  That property contains an array.  At index 0 of the array, is another Object, which is the Object where your `xml` property resides.